# Is the network performance of WKWebView slower than native safari?

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari, ios9, wkwebview

**Pre-statements**:

App developed in Objective-C on iOS9.

Implemented the app with WKWebView, and have it load an Angular SPA.

We have been noticing some network slowness in the application. We have the app running, as well as Safari open running the same loaded URL.

We are seeing 2-3x slower perf in the application, vs running it in Safari.

**Question:**

Is this something that is known about using a webview vs native safari, or even a native application? Are there any known optimizations to increase network performance in the webview?

We used the WKWebView for speed of development, since we are all web devs, but are thinking we might want to switch to a native application.

Comment: Check `SFSafariViewController`.  If I understand correctly, `WKWebView` has no JIT for executing JS.

Comment: @Avi according to the docs, the SFSafariViewController has a backbutton, shows url, etc.. our app cant have that. It needs to look like an iOS app, but behind the scenes its a webapp... I know companies like uber, evernote, twitter, instagram all use the webapp. They all are much more high performant than ours!

Answer (score 3):

Since iOS 8, WKWebView has the same performances as Safari, as you can read [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-quality-of-UIWebView-less-than-Safari).

I had a slow loading due to the fact that WKWebView doesn't use JIT rendering of JS by default.

After some research I found my solution here:

```
webView.configuration.suppressesIncrementalRendering = true
```